# jquery mobile sliding

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I want to swipe the images vertically in mobile using mobile jQuery . I found some links about jCarousel in jQuery about sliding vertically and horizontally in my case I want to have to swipe the images without arrow. I found one example and I exactly want to do this without arrow .

http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified#example8

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a [simple blog post](http://itdiary.mayuonline.com/simple-basic-image-carousel-with-jquery-mobile/) about it. Check it out... Basically you need to catch the swipe left and swipe right events and change images from your array.

```
 $("#myImagePage").swiperight(function () {
        if (i < (imgURL.length - 1)) {
            i++
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
        var imgStr = "<img src=" + imgURL[i] + " style='width:100%'>";
        $('#ImageDiv').html(imgStr);
    });
    $("#myImagePage").swipeleft(function () {
        if (i > 0) {
            i--
        } else {
            i = (imgURL.length - 1);
        }
        var imgStr = "<img src=" + imgURL[i] + " style='width:100%'>";
        $('#ImageDiv').html(imgStr);
    });
```

Here is a workign [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3bZ8/13/)

Comment: thanks for the reply can u tell me how can i do this with swipe up and down ?

Comment: Check the code above and check the fiddle link I've given above. Those are explaining how to do this stuff.

Comment: i check both ,  they have only swiperight and swipeleft event . I want to do the same with swipeup and swipedown , does jquery mobile support swipe up and down ?

Comment: Nativly it supports only left and right. You may try some plugins. Check out this link http://swipeplanes-jquery.blogspot.com/

Comment: aa ok , I found this  
http://developingwithstyle.blogspot.com/2010/11/jquery-mobile-swipe-up-down-left-right.html

I can able to do swipe up and down through that